# Oblivious Transfer in E-Voting

Tags: oblivious-transfer, voting

I'm having trouble understanding why and how an [oblivious transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblivious_transfer) (OT) is used in [e-voting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_voting) systems.

According to many descriptions of OT's, a receiver (I suppose that's the ballot collector?) can choose whether he wants to receive $m_0$ or $m_1$ from the sender (the voter?).

How is it used in e-voting, and what security property does it help to achieve?

Comment: There are a lot of different schemes for e-voting, and every one of them is set up differently. But in general, the choice (in OT) is made by the voter, based on the party he wants to vote for. And then that message contains some kind of token, which allows him to cast a vote for that party. By using OT, no one knows which vote/token was received by the voter. Of course, there are more step,s e.g. making sure the vote isn't recognizable later, that it is included in the ballot, etc.